# VBA and "Class doesn't support Automation or does not support expected interface"

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba, com

I have .NET assembly with ComVisible class. Some days ago (I can find that moment exactly, by git) something happened - Excel doesn't see anymore this class. So:

I have interface

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface MyInterface { ... }
```

and class

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ProgId("MyClass.Id")]
public class MyClass { ... }
```

Excel creates the instance by

```
Dim c as MyClass
Set c = New MyClass
```

Earlier everything worked like a charm, but after **deleting** some methods (from interface and class) Excel is crazy - it shows me an error `Class doesn't support Automation or does not support expected interface`. Where can be a problem?

- I checked everything some times. Error occurs exactly after deleting some methods
- This class is partial (maybe the problem is somewhere here?)
- Earlier everything worked..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Damn three times. For the future guys: after removing methods/properties from your COM-library you should re-add reference to .tlb file in your Excel's file.

Comment: I did not delete anything still getting error how to solve it?

Comment: @Shrivallabh Well, as I said - removing and adding back reference to .tlb file in Excel sheet helped me. Not sure that it's your case too..