# using .NET dll from vb6 gives Run-time error 430  Class does not support automation

Tags: .net, vb6

I have A VB6 application which I have made some changes to. This references a dll created in .NET 2 which I also changed. When I changed the dll, I built it and overwrote the dll in the VB project.

Now when I start the VB6 exe I get the following error:

> Run-time error 430. Class does not support automation or does not support expected interface

Any help in how I debug or deal with this would be great thanks.

UPDATE: I think it's bombing out here

```
Set  get_datalist = New ADODB.Recordset
```

I think it may be the MDAC stuff, as I built the app on a Win 7 machine and I am trying to run on windows xp.

SOLVED: I ended up building the project on an XP machine, thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA and "Class doesn't support Automation or does not support expected interface"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817215/vba-and-class-doesnt-support-automation-or-does-not-support-expected-interface)

Comment: @GSerg just because its the same error message doesn't necessarily make it a duplicate! There are a lot of causes for error 430

Comment: @MarkJ I honestly believe the underlying reason is the same, and [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8817954/11683) will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it may be the MDAC stuff, as I built the app on a Win 7 machine

It no doubt is, note how it bombs on ADODB.Recordset and nothing related to your .NET code.  There was a long overdue update released for ADO in Windows 7 SP1.  It solves a nagging problem with type library compatibility for 64-bit code.  This was however a *breaking* change and required new guids for the ADO interface types.

Which is what the message is telling you, your program was built to work with the updated version of ADO, the XP machine is still running the old version.  The core KB article [is here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2517589).

Answer (score 2):

To see what changes have been made in the .Net dll, you can use OLE View to inspect the typelibrary.  Do like this:

1. Open OLE View
2. Goto File->View Typelib....  Choose the old version of the .tlb file from your .Net object.
3. Save the IDL file as text
4. Repeat 2 & 3 for the new version of the .tlb file
5. Use a file comparison tool to compare the two .idl files.

What this will reveal is differences in interface names, GUIDs etc.

If you want to keep your OLE interface backwards compatible, you need to insure that the new version uses the same GUID for interface ID, and that the function use the same parameters and return values.

Comment: The GUID hasn't changed or has the interface. Im starting to thinks its something else, there about 15 other dlls in the project.

Comment: Do you mean you only get the error when you run your compiled .exe, not when in debug mode in VB6?  Or do you get the error before you reach the first line in your code in debug mode?

Comment: It works fine in debug, I get the error when I run the compiled exe.